# Know about Mapping or Routing against Sales Order page when we put item code automates item tax template and taxes and charges

Tags: javascript, python, html, erpnext, frappe

Hiiii Teams
In ERPNext Version 14 , how to find location of source code for sales order page where we put item code , automatically they fetch item tax template and taxes and chargers sections, how to know about that mapping and routing if that page works , I want to understand source code file which may be .js file or .py file, please help me to find that particular location where they connect in erpnext v14, so i can easily debug code

I want to understand source code file which may be .js file or .py file, please help me to find that particular location where they connect in erpnext v14, so i can easily debug code